# ImportError: No module named prop2part (TuLiP)

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors

Using TuLiP module in Python, an error message always appears when I try to compile a code I have :

`ImportError: No module named prop2part`

In the code, initialization contains :

```
import sys, os
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), '..'))
from prop2part import Region, PropPreservingPartition
```

Any ideas why the error appears ?

Comment: For posterity: `pip install tulip` or from its repository, then adjust your imports: `PropPreservingPartition` is in [`tulip.abstract.prop2partition`](https://github.com/tulip-control/tulip-control/blob/1ad5b12ce1f96253d898abb8485d4e0ca8d20d90/tulip/abstract/prop2partition.py#L433), and `Region` can be found in the module [`polytope.polytope`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/f4c0cb4ce7bf60ad32d90e34770d4cefc2ce7af0/polytope/polytope.py#L631) of the `polytope` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download prop2part module from this link `http://tulip-control.sourceforge.net/doc/_modules/prop2part.html` Then append the downloaded path either in sys.path list or you can move the downloaded module in any of the path available in the sys.path.

Comment: can you please add more detail ?? How do I append the downloaded path either in sys.path list or in any path in the sys.path ??

Comment: I looked for prop2part on my laptop and actually found it there...So not sure what's wrong. How can I make sure it's in the correct path ?

Comment: Add the following piece of code import sys \n sys.path.append('<path where you have found the prop2path python module>')

Comment: I get an error `File "vms5.py", line 5 sys.path.append('</Users/G/Documents/ex/tulip-0.3c/tulip/>')   SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` with a small arrow under the last bracket

Comment: your path must not have angular brackets

Comment: not sure what you mean ..tried removing angular brackets there and the same error appears.

Comment: Now what error you are getting exactly? Which Operating system you are using? Also have you added `__init__.py` in the folder /Users/G/Documents/ex/tulip-0.3c/tulip/

Comment: Same error : `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` -- Using MacOSX, Python 2.7

Comment: Here is the problem replace line `import sys \n sys.path.append('/Users/G/Documents/ex/tulip-0.3c/tulip/')` with `sys.path.append('/Users/G/Documents/ex/tulip-0.3c/tulip/')`